# How to measure the difference in execution time between bash commands?

Tags: bash, performance

When given two bash commands `command1` and `command2` how do you measure the difference in execution time? Ideally, I want this to be directional and not in absolute. Millisecond accuracy is preferred.

I can achieve this by code, but the way I do it feels very cumbersome in comparison.

```
#!/bin/env bash

command1=$1
command2=$2
time1=$(/usr/bin/time -f "%E" $command1 2>&1 >/dev/null |\
 awk -F: '{secs=$3; secs+=$2*60; sec+=$3*3600; printf "%.3f\n", secs*1000}')
time2=$(/usr/bin/time -f "%E" $command2 2>&1 >/dev/null |\
 awk -F: '{secs=$3; secs+=$2*60; sec+=$3*3600; printf "%.3f\n", secs*1000}')
time_diff=$(echo "$time1 - $time2" | bc)
echo $time_diff
```

Comment: Is it adequate if the output is accurate to the second?

Comment: @Cyrus, not really, and I updated the question to clarify. I will still upvote a solution like that if it is sufficiently interesting and teaches me something.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just:

```
start=$(date +%s.%N)
command1
mid=$(date +%s.%N)
command2
stop=$(date +%s.%N)
time_diff=$(bc -l <<<"($mid - $start) - ($stop - $mid)")
echo "$time_diff"
```

or yet better

```
start=$EPOCHREALTIME
command1
mid=$EPOCHREALTIME
command2
stop=$EPOCHREALTIME
time_diff=$(bc -l <<<"($mid - $start) - ($stop - $mid)")
echo "$time_diff"
```

Comment: Since you are using Bash specific redirection, then use Bash specific variables: `LC_NUMERIC=C; start=$EPOCHREALTIME; command1; mid=$EPOCHREALTIME; command2; stop=$EPOCHREALTIME; ...` Since there is no spawning of the date command subshell, the measurement is more accurate.

Comment: Kamil, if I can ask, why `bc -l` instead of `bc`? And why did you prefer to use `here string` instead of `echo` or `here doc`? Not a criticism, asking to learn.

Comment: `why bc -l instead of bc?` The default scale=0, so `bc` would result in no digits after comma, in `bc -l` default `scale=20`. `why did you prefer to use here string` `echo` spawns a separate process, so is slower, here doc is more to type.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ begs[1]=$EPOCHREALTIME; sleep 1; ends[1]=$EPOCHREALTIME
$ begs[2]=$EPOCHREALTIME; sleep 3; ends[2]=$EPOCHREALTIME
$ awk -v bs="${begs[*]}" -v es="${ends[*]}" 'BEGIN {
    split(bs,begs)
    split(es,ends)
    for (i in begs) {
        durs[i] = ends[i] - begs[i]
    }
    print durs[2] - durs[1]
}'
2.0128
```

If you want to profile the times of a bunch of commands, though, then consider writing a small script to execute each command and print the timing information, e.g.:

```
$ cat tst.sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

cnt=0
while IFS= read -p 'Cmd> ' -r cmd; do
    if [[ "$cmd" == "." ]]; then
        break
    fi
    cnt=$(( cnt + 1 ))
    cmds["$cnt"]="$cmd"
    begs["$cnt"]=$EPOCHREALTIME
    eval "$cmd"
    ends["$cnt"]=$EPOCHREALTIME
done

awk '
    FILENAME == ARGV[1] { begs[FNR] = $0; next }
    FILENAME == ARGV[2] { ends[FNR] = $0; next }
    {
        cmds[FNR] = $0
        durs[FNR] = ends[FNR] - begs[FNR]

        print  "---"
        printf "Cmd = %s\n", cmds[FNR]
        printf "Dur = %f\n", durs[FNR]
        printf "Chg = %f\n", (FNR>1 ? durs[FNR] - durs[FNR-1] : 0)
    }' \
        <(printf '%s\n' "${begs[@]}") \
        <(printf '%s\n' "${ends[@]}") \
        <(printf '%s\n' "${cmds[@]}") \
            >&2
```

which you can run as shown below and get the output also shown below:

```
$ ./tst.sh
Cmd> date -d today +'%F %T'
2023-11-18 06:22:38
Cmd> sleep 1
Cmd> seq 10000000 > /dev/null
Cmd> echo "$(date)"
Sat Nov 18 06:23:14 CST 2023
Cmd> sleep 2
Cmd> .
---
Cmd = date -d today +'%F %T'
Dur = 0.019273
Chg = 0.000000
---
Cmd = sleep 1
Dur = 1.021269
Chg = 1.001996
---
Cmd = seq 10000000 > /dev/null
Dur = 0.341198
Chg = -0.680071
---
Cmd = echo "$(date)"
Dur = 0.023039
Chg = -0.318159
---
Cmd = sleep 2
Dur = 2.019530
Chg = 1.996491
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know what your comment means. If you have a followup question, though, then just ask a new question rather than putting it in a comment.

Comment: I think that this is the sort of thing that if you start expanding its capabilities it would be better implemented as a compiled binary. What do you think?

Comment: Not necessarily, it depends what it does, how many times per second it's going to be called, etc. Don't assume something compiled runs faster than something interpreted - that's not always the case. Interpreted awk scripts are frequently faster than compiled C programs for text processing, for example, because all of the code for reading input, splitting into fields, dynamically resizing array memory, implementing hash tables, etc. that is built into awk is highly optimized in the awk command while individuals have to write it themselves in C and probably won't do nearly as good a job.

Comment: Even if an interpreted script was slower than a compiled binary, it'll almost certainly be fast enough for your needs (and require far less coding) unless it's being called many times per second in some system that needs to run at blistering speeds. And if it IS too slow there's an excellent chance it's because you did something wrong when you wrote it and there's a much faster, still interpreted, alternative (e.g. if you wrote a shell while-read loop to manipulate text instead of calling awk to do it magnitudes faster).

Answer (score 2):

Avoid `date` and `time` and use the builtin `SECONDS`.

```
SECONDS=0
command1
firststop=$SECONDS
SECONDS=0
command2
echo "Diff $((SECONDS - firststop))."
```

Example

```
SECONDS=0
sleep 4
firststop=$SECONDS
SECONDS=0
sleep 7
echo "Diff $((SECONDS - firststop))."
# Returns...
Diff 3.
```

Comment: This loses the milliseconds from `time` or the nanoseconds from `date`. I don't think nanoseconds are particularly meaningful but if I run this multiple times and aggregate the data the milliseconds could prove meaningful. I think.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ command1(){ sleep 5; }
$ command2(){ sleep 2; }

$ { (time command1) 2>&1; (time command2) 2>&1; } | 
    awk -F'real *|m|s' '
        /real/{
            a[i+=1]=($2*60)+$3
        }
        END{
            print "time1:", a[1]
            print "time2:", a[2]
            print "diff:", a[1]-a[2]
        }
    ' 
time1: 5.008
time2: 2.011
diff: 2.997
```